# Update CONCAT creates duplicate date entry

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

I am trying to `CONCAT` new data to existing data in a text field, and it works, but the date (which I am adding through date('d-m-Y') is duplicated.

I have this:

```
    $insert_query = "UPDATE `event_registrations` SET 
`changereqhistory` = CONCAT_WS('\n','$addition',`changereqhistory`)
WHERE `guid` = '$GUID'";
```

and as you can see I am trying to concatenate $addition to the existing field "changereqhistory".
$addition is defined as:

```
$addition = date('d.m.Y H:i')." - ".$_SESSION['myusername']." | ".$changereq;
```

and `$changereq` is simply a post value.

What i get is something like this:

```
18.12.2013 16:31 - myusername@mydomain.com | 
18.12.2013 16:31 - myusername@mydomain.com | More posted text to be added
18.12.2013 16:31 - myusername@mydomain.com | 
18.12.2013 16:31 - myusername@mydomain.com | Posted text to be added
```

while I should actually get this:

```
18.12.2013 16:31 - myusername@mydomain.com | More posted text to be added
18.12.2013 16:31 - myusername@mydomain.com | Posted text to be added
```

Why is it that after the posted text is added, another new "empty" line is added (with the datetime, username and the "|" but no text)...?

Thank you for your help.

---

full code where it is saved:

```
$changereqhistory = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['changereqhistory']);
$changereq = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['changereq']);

$addition = date('d.m.Y H:i')." - ".$_SESSION['myusername']." | ".$changereq;

//let's create the query
if ($GUID == $guidrow['guid']) {
    $insert_query = "UPDATE `event_registrations` SET 
    `changereqhistory` = CONCAT_WS('\n','$addition',`changereqhistory`)
    WHERE `guid` = '$GUID'";
}
//run the query
mysql_query($insert_query);
```

---

code where it is shown:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="2">Change Request History:<br><textarea name="changereqhistory" readonly="readonly" style="width:100%; height:300px;border:1px solid #666666;font-size:11px"><?php echo $guidrow['changereqhistory'];?></textarea>
<textarea id="changereq" name="changereq" rows="3"></textarea><br>Write your notes here ↑
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Can you show the code where this is being called? I am suspicious you are executing this twice, once with an empty `$changereq`

Comment: where have you declaired $changereq ..show us full code

Comment: I suspect you're executing this code when the page is first loaded, even if there is no POST data. Make sure to check that the form has actually been submitted before running the update.

Comment: Thanks Everett, I inserted an if $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and NOW ITS OK!